# Round Number in Java

Tags: java, numbers, floating

How to I round a number in Java? Like, I have this number `3.4666666666663` and i would like to round it to the nearest floating number, which would be 3.5. I don't want to round it to 4

Comment: When you say "this number", what is it to begin with? A `float`? A `double`? A `BigDecimal`?

Comment: I believe your definition of _nearest floating number_ is not universally accepted.

Comment: @Keppil basically i want to round the number to the next floating number with 1 number after the ., for example '2.444424' to '2.5', '5.66764' to '5.7'

Comment: You have not answered my question yet; it has a huge impact on the answer you seek

Comment: @fge It's a `double` 

`double a = (n1 * 4) - 60;
 Double b = (a * -1) / 6;
 cp_nota2.setText(b + "");`

Answer (score 3):

You have a few options, you might use a [`DecimalFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html), or a `BigDecimal` or even a `String.format()` like

```
double v = 3.4666666666663;
NumberFormat nf = new DecimalFormat("#.0");
System.out.println(nf.format(v));
MathContext mc = new MathContext(2);
System.out.println(BigDecimal.valueOf(v).round(mc));
System.out.printf("%.1f%n", v);
```

Output is

```
3.5
3.5
3.5
```

Comment: Should be mentioned, that the first and the third method use the locale specific decimal seperator.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you multiply it by 10, round that up, then divide by 10.